# composer install does not use ssh key on private repo (permission denied public key)

Tags: windows, git, ssh, composer-php

I have a Laravel project with some dependencies to private packages, secured through ssh, working on windows 10 with Laragon.

On composer install I get a permission denied (public key), however, if I clone the repo directly I get my regular prompt to type the ssh-key password for authentication and the clone works with no problems (using git@gitlab...., so no https).

The output looks like this:

`Failed to execute git clone ...
 Cloning into 'project/path/foo/bar'...
 Permission denied (public key).
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
 and the repository exists.`

I already added the host (a private GitLab server) to my git config file, including the path to my ssh key, which seems to work due to git clone succeeding.

I expected that composer install would prompt for the password, but it just stops.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? I normally work on Ubuntu and didn't have such a problem before.

**Edit:**

Tried out the same commands with git bash (Git for windows) and it worked. But if I use Powershell or ConEmu(through Laragon) it won't work, any ideas?

Comment: I faced the same issue, tried with Git Bash and it worked.